# NullPointerException when I use startactivity in kotlin(crashing)

Tags: android, kotlin

i want to move "detail" activity when button was clicked. 
but, when button was clicked, app(?) crashed.
I looked over for the internet but couldn't find the answer.

What should I do?

(MainActivity.kt)code

```
package com.example.practice

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.practice.dataclass.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.content.Intent
import com.example.practice.detail
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_detail.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(this, detail::class.java)!!
            startActivity(i)

        }

    }
}
```

logcat

```
2020-04-12 19:09:39.388 13201-13201/com.example.practice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.practice, PID: 13201
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.practice.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:18)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7350)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7327)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:807)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28166)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7464)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.practice">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".detail"></activity>
    </application>
```

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: Intent(this, detail::class.java) instead of Intent(this, detail::class.java)!!

Comment: sorry but it didn't work

Comment: val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, detail::class.java)
            startActivity(i)

Comment: why are you using !! in there? Intent won't return you null, which Intent you're using what is your import statement

Comment: Have you created the object of button3 by findviewById ?

Comment: no,  I haven not.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add all of the `import` statements in `MainActivity`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to do it, can you show me with code?

Comment: At the top of your `MainActivity` class, between the `package` statement, and the `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()` line, there is a section of lines that start with `import`. It might be collapsed, so you'd have to expand it. Please [edit] your question to add all of those to the `MainActivity` class here.

Comment: `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_detail.*` – That's likely the source of the issue. I would bet that you have some `View` in the `activity_detail` layout that has an ID of `detail`. That's causing a `detail` property to be created in `MainActivity` that is going to return null because that's not the layout that `MainActivity` loads. Remove that line, and let us know if you have any compiler errors when you do that.

Comment: button3 is defined in activity_main layout?

Answer (score 0):

Your button click listener should be like this:

```
  button3.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, detail::class.java)
            startActivity(i)

        }
```

where **DetailActivity** is your next activity on which you want to after clicking
**button3**

Comment: Please try to rename your activity name like Detail.and share your Detail activity code as well.

Comment: It cannot be raised because it is long

Comment: Are you getting same errror ?

Comment: Make sure you have extends detail activity with AppCompatActivity() class.

Comment: detail activity class should be with .kt extension like detail.kt. and please try to get button3 reference via findViewById() once.

Comment: got same errror

Comment: sometimes getting direct reference without using findViewById cause problem

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to do it, can you show me with code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211464/discussion-between-black4guy-and-kimhanuu).

Comment: can you show me with code yes please check in the chat

Comment: try again by removing this line             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

Comment: Please let me know one thing do you have button3 in activity_detail XML as well ?